# why in intrinsic semiconductor positive Silicon atom is known as hole but in extrinsic semiconductor positive Phosphorus is immobile ion?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

why in intrinsic semiconductor positive Silicon atom is known as hole but in extrinsic semiconductor positive Phosphorus is not hole

Answer (score 1):

> positive Silicon atom is known as hole

This is not correct. A hole is not an atom.

I'm not sure I can adequately explain what a hole actually is without taking you through a whole introductory solid state physics course, but I'll try for the 10¢ tour version:

Within a single crystal of silicon, electrons in what you might have learned to call the outer "shell" or "band" of electron states don't associate just with one silicon nucleus. They spread out so that we say that they interact with the crystal lattice as a hole rather than with the individual silicon nuclei.

Despite the electrons in the outer (or *valence*) band being disassociated from any particular nucleus, they aren't able to move freely because (in absolutely pure intrinsic silicon) all of the valence band states are occupied.

But suppose one electron, due to thermal energy for example, jumps to a higher energy band (what we call the *conduction band*). Since the conduction band is otherwise unoccupied, this electron is free to move, and as it moves around it contributes to current.

But also, this promoted electron left behind an empty state in the valence band. This empty state allows all the other electrons in the valence band a slight freedom of motion because it's no longer true that all the valence band states are occupied. However this freedom of motion is quite constricted because there's only one particular state unoccupied, with it's particular energy and momentum properties.

It turns out that rather than keep track of how all the electrons in the valence band shift in and out of a single unoccupied state, we can simply treat the unoccupied state as a particle of its own, and this unoccupied state particle is what we call an *electron hole*. The electron hole behaves as if it has all the properties of a physical particle, such as mass, energy, momentum, and charge, and it interacts with the lattice just as any other charged particle would, so we quickly stop worrying about its origins as an unoccupied state and analyze our semiconductor structures and devices as having two types of charge carriers: electrons and holes.